# How do you import a specific song in to iTunes?

Tags: itunes

How do I import a specific song, not already in my iTunes library, in to iTunes?

Comment: Just double click o it or in iTunes do File->Add to Library

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Preferences -> Advanced, uncheck "Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to Library". Drag the media file you want to add into the iTunes window, or use the "Library -> Add to Library" option in the File menu.

Comment: to clarify - iTunes will always add to the Library, but won't necessarily add a copy of the file to the default Library location.

Comment: Either of those methods (drag & Add) will do the import.  It is not necessary to change the copy/not copy preference.